# How to extract and parse commands of shellscript to file?

Tags: bash, shell, heroku, append, string-concatenation

I have the following program in `Shell Script`:

```
#!/bin/sh

max=9
for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app0${i}
done

max=50
for i in `seq 10 $max`
do
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app${i}
done
```

The result of each line of the for command is:

```
=== mws-usp-app01 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@<hostname>/<defaultschema>?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-50-19-219-148.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/de4hk500aj9f1q
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
=== mws-usp-app02 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@<hostname>/<defaultschema>?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-50-19-219-148.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/de4hk500aj9f1q
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
...
=== mws-usp-app50 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@<hostname>/<defaultschema>?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-54-243-204-86.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5gngl61fsq95o
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

How to parse `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` to get all values of `<user>`, `<password>`, `<hostname>` and `<defaultschema>` and put them inside a text file?

======================================

## The correct script after the response:

```
#!/bin/sh

max=9
for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    echo "mws-usp-app0${i}";
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app0${i} | sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*\):\(.*\)@.*/\1 \2/p' >> usernames.txt
done

max=50
for i in `seq 10 $max`
do
    echo "mws-usp-app${i}";
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app${i} | sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*\):\(.*\)@.*/\1 \2/p' >> usernames.txt
done
```

---

```
$> chmod +x script.sh
$> sudo ./script.sh
```

---

Comment: Can you post a sample `<user>`, `<password>` values from one such instance?

Comment: Hello @Inian, one sample would be: `<user> = b69ab75f269r50` `<password> = c6f5230r6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your output is in a file called input.txt you can use sed:

```
  sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*:.*\)@.*/\1/p' input.txt > usernames.txt
```

alternatively use the output of your shell script immediately:

```
  <your_script> | sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*:.*\)@.*/\1/p' > usernames.txt
```

There might be an easier way, but that's what came fastest into my mind ;)

Comment: Hello A. Grieco, I did the following in the two loops for: `sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app0${i} | sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*:.*\)@.*/\1/p' > usernames.txt`, However only the user and password values of the first `mws-usp-app01`.

Comment: In the file usernames.txt appeared only the value "ab526723abc4762:0bd236b9" how do I change the sign of `:`
by a space?

Comment: `sed -n 's/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.*mysql:\/\/\(.*\):\(.*\)@.*/\1 \2/p' >> usernames.txt` seperates username and password with a space. The `>>` appends at the end of the file rather then rewriting it. Please comment if it's still not working for you. Without your script it's hard to test ;)

Comment: Hello @ A. Grieco, It worked, but only the first line of the text file was marked with `:` how should I remove it?

Comment: Actually, one more line appeared, how do I insert the number of each line before `<user>` to `<password>`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help A. Grieco! I was able to find out what was wrong. Now everything is working properly! :)

Comment: Hello @A. Grieco, I would like to know if you could give me your email, because I ended up forgetting a very important detail and I do not know how to work with regular expressions

Comment: No sorry I won't publically post my mail adresse over here. Please ask another question or, even better, update this one. Then I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: No problem, my doubt is very simple, beyond the `<user>` and `<password>`   I need to get also what's after the `@`  sign up to the `/` and then get what is after the `/` until the `?`. For example `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_cf843140f07f0a2?reconnect=true` Values I want to get in each line of the file `<user>` `<password>` `us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net` and `heroku_cf843140f07f0a2`. Please let me know if I can explain it right.

Comment: Hello @A. Grieco, I updated my question. An example of `<hostname>` is `us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net` and an example of` `<defaultschema>`is `heroku_cf843140f07f0a2`. Could you help me with regular expressions?